# Angular2 Karma test with JS Library returns ReferenceError

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, angular-cli

I included the Google API JS Library in my Angular-Cli project and installed the types so I had no problems during coding. But when I want to test the service I get a `ReferenceError: gapi is not defined` Error

I don't pass it in the constructor, it is a global function

```
private checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: calendarApi,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
      immediate: true,
    }, this.next())};
```

Test file:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CalendarService } from './calendar.service';

describe('Service: Calendar', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [CalendarService]
    });
  });

  it('should ...', inject([CalendarService], (service: CalendarService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

The gapi is from this file `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js`

So do I have to include something in my Test file or do I have to configure angular-cli to recognize the reference?

**Eidt:**
I included the file in the `karma.conf.js` file. Now he finds the variable but non of its methods.

Comment: Maybe you need to [add it to the scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation)?

Comment: I included it directly in the `index.html` file. But importing it via the `angular-cli.json` gives me the same error while testing.

Comment: Try importing into the test. Aside from making it work, are you sure you actually want to make an XHR call from inside your test?

Comment: If you can't get it to work, can you tell me what I need to install. I can play with it

Comment: I don't want to make a test call. I just want to make sure that the service can be loaded.

Comment: I used angular-cli and just included the JS API from Google to test it.

Comment: What NPM package(s) did you install? I don't use it so I don't know

Comment: I used `angular-cli` and included the JS file inside the index file.

Comment: But you said you installed the "types"

Comment: `typings` has a package for this library to install the typings, but it is not supported in the `npm`.

Comment: I didn't try to install the `typings` because I saw the project doesn't use any. It just uses `@types`. So I installed `npm install --save-dev @types/gapi` and it worked. I had to restart VSCode though after installing to get rid of IDE errors

Comment: I also tried this but I still get the Reference Error while testing.

Comment: What CLI version are you using? I'm using beta.16

Comment: I use the same version.